# How to add reference to Mono.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm developing a class library for Android using Xamarin Studio. How do I add a reference to Mono.Android in my library project?
Mono.Android is not in the list of available assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have X.Android **installed**, right click your solution. Then `Add -> Add new Project -> Android -> Android Library Project`.

There is no reference you would have to add.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I started with a ordinary class library. I don't know how I  could miss the Android library.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support more than simply Xamarin.Android in your Library project, you have the possibility of using a Portable Class Library (PCL). I find the profiles 78 and 158 to work very well and both provide await/async support.

However you should not that the PCL's only support the minimum subset of the targets in the profile. Hence, not everything in .NET 4.5 is available, and you won't be able to do platform specific things inside of it, unless you abstract it away. This could be achieved by creating Interfaces and injecting the implementations using IoC.

IoC can be provided by [TinyIoC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC) and the [IoC inside of MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/CrossLight).

Comment: I also find Jonathan Pepper's service container very simple to use. https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XPlatUtils/blob/master/XPlatUtils/ServiceContainer.cs or for more utils https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XPlatUtils

Comment: UPDATE: PCL's are now recommended to be done via .NET Standard. Its essentially a PCL, but specifies additional details, to guarantee cross-platform compatibility, for any device that declares support for the given .NET Standard version. "2.0" is a good target as I write this. Put all your *portable* code into one of these "portable" libraries, including *Interfaces* for APIs you need to customize per platform. Then for each platform, create a platform-specific library that provides the APIs needed by your portable library. Then any device simply needs the portable lib + the device lib.

Comment: ... to handle platform-specific types, such as UI types, there are various techniques for "wrapping" the platform-specific type, so your main app code and the portable library can pass objects around, without the portable code knowing the platform-specific type. Where possible, create a portable representation. E.g. use Xamarin.Forms.Color, and have each platform contain a converter to the native color object when needed.

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason your Xamarin Android project is missing Mono.Android reference, it can be manually added in the project's .csproj, by adding this line:

```
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
```

This goes in the first "ItemGroup". Look for `<Reference Include="mscorlib" />`, and put it before that. (Order doesn't matter, it just needs to be inside an ItemGroup, but that is alphabetic order, so I put it there).

In my case, I had deleted obsolete references from an old Xamarin Android, and I thought that Mono.Android was out-of-date and would be reinstalled when I updated Xamarin Forms, so I deleted it. Mistake.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\Mono.Android.dll

For VS2017, the libarary can be found at above location.